# Insert IF value X has increased in an another table

Tags: mysql, sql

OK. So:
I have an app that reads value X from a realtime table and then it inserts the info from that table to a record table, and users of that app can check their what is their record high value X. 
I'm trying to make it so that it will only do that IF player's value X has increased in the realtime table. 
Currently it is like this:

```
 - Player's value X is currently 10 in the real time table
   - It gets inserted into the record table 
 - Player's value X is now 8 the real time table
   - It gets inserted into the record table 
 - Player's value X is now 7 the real time table
   - It gets inserted into the record table
```

So now, the record table has inserted every value he has had. I'd like to make it so that it would only do that if Value is higher then the highest value that currently is in the record table:

```
 - Player's value X is currently 10 in the real time table
   - It gets inserted into the record table 
 - Player's value X is now 8 the real time table
   - It gets ignored cause recordtable.value > realtimetable.value
 - Player's value X is now 7 the real time table
   - It gets ignored cause recordtable.value > realtimetable.value
```

This is to avoid unneccesary lines in the table. Is this even possible to be done with just mysql? Of course it can be done in python, but I have not sufficient skills in that, so this is my only chance atm.

Comment: Hmm, thanks, I'll take a look. What's the reason for this to not work:
REPLACE INTO recordtable (`client_id` , `value`) SELECT distinct recordtable.client_id, recordtable.value FROM `recordtable`, realtimetable WHERE (realtimetable.value > recordtable.value)

Answer (score 2):

Write some code otherwise I have to put my finger on the trigger (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html). Do you feel lucky punk?

(Clint Eastwood btw)

Comment: Nice *comment*, though.

Comment: @Ravinder - It was an answer dressed up a little

Comment: (He never actually says that!)